# jquery contains with class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

I'm using jQuery :contains selector to filter through some link tags.  The following code works great.

```
$('a:contains("string")').each(function(i){
//do some stuff
});
```

I'd like only run this function if the anchor tags are inside a specific class, I've tried the following but it does not appear to work:

```
$('.my_class a:contains("string")').each(function(i){
//do some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those will work. You've got brackets and mis matching quotes all over the shop.

```
$('a:contains(string)').each(function(i){
    //do some stuff
});
```

and then

```
$('.my_class a:contains(string)').each(function(i){
    //do some stuff
});
```

Which now works: http://www.jsfiddle.net/muzQQ/

Comment: thanks for the catch.  Looks Like I had some mis matching going on.

Answer (score 3):

To select by class name, put a dot at the start:

```
$('.my_class a:contains("string")')
```

Comment: actually, I had a typo.  I included a '.' for the class and it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with a dot at the start of the class name:

```
$('.my_class a:contains('string').each(function(i){
//do some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="GridCell">Click to review.</div>
```

if you need to get the above using jQuery, use

```
$('div.GridCell:contains(Click to review.)')
```